# Should I not ask a question on Physics Stack Exchange if I have already asked a similar question on Aviation Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Is it recommended not to ask a question on Physics Stack Exchange if the same user has already asked a very similar question on [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour)?

I have received a message (from another user who is not a moderator) to the effect that this is the case and I should delete one of my questions.

My intent was simply to solicit the expertise of a different group of people who might approach the problem from a different viewpoint.

Thanks for any guidance on this.

In case it matters, I did note in the question that I had asked a similar question on ASE-- and provided a link to it-- looking at the edit history it appears that I added this note a few hours after the sole answer had been posted, and about three hours after I posted the question.

This is the question -- [Is this vector diagram of the forces at play in turning flight correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548011/is-this-vector-diagram-of-the-forces-at-play-in-turning-flight-correct)

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but the question was poorly-received on ASE.  But I have no wish to delete the question from ASE.  I feel that it highlights a significant flaw in the current flight training curriculum.

Comment: We have quite a few questions this is a duplicate of -- I picked one that seemed most representative. TLDR -- you can cross-post if you want the perspective of a different group, but your question should be tailored to make that clear.

Comment: @tpg2114: Which one?

Comment: @PeterMortenson -- question is now linked in meta question above

Comment: There is a hole a system: the system does not know and can not track "cross-site dupes". So, *asking the same* on multiple sites is forbidden. *But asking similars on multiple sites is okay.* Furthermore, *if your question would be a dupe of a question on another site, and not you posted it, no one cares.*

Comment: I typically do this on a way, that I ask for multiple aspects of the same problem, on multiple sites. That is perfectly okay. I like to even cite the link to the question on the other site, to provide additional context.

Comment: However, this question asks for *similar* ones and not from exact duplicates. On this reason, I believe it is not the dupe of the question asking from (exact) cross-site dupes.

Comment: @quietflyer Note, the question should be enough different in the eyes of the (sometimes very deletionist) reviewers, and not in yours. So make them so different as you only can.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I shouldn't have. 
 I have now found this -- [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) .  As for what to do next-- guess I'll have to ask a second question to PSE meta.

This is the question -- [Is this vector diagram of the forces at play in turning flight correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548011/is-this-vector-diagram-of-the-forces-at-play-in-turning-flight-correct)